# Swift Core Data - How to update attributes of all child entities?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have one entity with an attribute named "type" which can be 0 or 1.
I can have lists and folders inside folders, same as in the finder. It is managed by an one-to-many relationship.

- Type 0: "folder".
- Type 1: "list".

This entity also has an attribute named "selected" which can be 0, 1 or 2.

- Selected 0: no child selected.
- Selected 1: at least one but not all children inside the folder are selected.
- Selected 2: all children inside the folder are selected.

When I mark (select) a folder I want to select all child lists or folder inside. This I can do it by checking all children (using the relationship) and `setValue(2, for key: "selected")`.

Question 1: how to update attributes for children of children (content of folders, inside folders, inside folders...)?

Question 2: how to unselect (set "selected" to 0 or 1) all parent lists and folders (until root level) if I unselect an entity inside a folder?

---

**EDIT:**
[datamodel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9UOO.png)

Comment: Please show your data model.

Comment: I added the data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve my problem by checking 1st level child objects in a `for` loop and adding them to an array (childFolderA).

Then I do 2 `for` loops inside a `while` loop:

1. The first `for` loop is identifying all child folder and add them to an array (childFolderB).
2. Then this array is scanned in the second `for` loop, and all child objects are added to an other array (childFolderA).
3. It will continue `while` childFolderA or childFolderB arrays contain something.

The code is in a function.

```
       // Find the list/folder object of the row selected
        if let objs = controller.fetchedObjects , objs.count > 0 {
            let item = objs[indexPath.row]

       // Manage selection for selected object.
       if item.selected == 0 || item.selected == 1 {
            item.selected = 2
        } else {
            item.selected = 0
        }

        var childFolderA: [List] = []
        var childFolderB: [List] = []

        // Find the 1st level child lists
        for child in item.child_lists! {
            if item.selected == 0 || item.selected == 1 {
                (child as AnyObject).setValue(0, forKey: "selected")
            } else {
                (child as AnyObject).setValue(2, forKey: "selected")
            }
            // Add all 1st level child to the array: childFolderA
            childFolderA.append(child as! List)
        }

        // Find all child folders and lists
        while (!childFolderA.isEmpty || !childFolderB.isEmpty) {
            for child in childFolderA {
                if child.type == 1 {                                                // Folder
                    for child2 in child.child_lists! {
                        if item.selected == 0 {
                            (child2 as AnyObject).setValue(0, forKey: "selected")   // Set selected circle to “All”
                        } else {
                            (child2 as AnyObject).setValue(2, forKey: "selected")   // Set selected circle to “0”
                        }
                        childFolderB.append(child2 as! List)
                    }
                } else {                                                            // List
                    if item.selected == 0 {
                        child.setValue(0, forKey: "selected")                       // Set selected circle to “one list”
                    } else {
                        child.setValue(1, forKey: "selected")                       // Set selected circle to “0”
                    }
                }
            }
            childFolderA.removeAll()                                                // Reset childFolderA

            for child in childFolderB {
                if child.type == 1 {                                                // Folder
                    for child2 in child.child_lists! {
                        if item.selected == 0 {
                            (child2 as AnyObject).setValue(0, forKey: "selected")   // Set selected circle to “All”
                        } else {
                            (child2 as AnyObject).setValue(2, forKey: "selected")   // Set selected circle to “0”
                        }
                        childFolderA.append(child2 as! List)
                    }

                } else {                                                            // List
                    if item.selected == 0 {
                        child.setValue(0, forKey: "selected")                       // Set selected circle to “one list”
                    } else {
                        child.setValue(1, forKey: "selected")                       // Set selected circle to “0”
                    }
                }
            }
            childFolderB.removeAll()                                                // Reset childFolderA
        }
        childFolderA.removeAll()
        childFolderB.removeAll()
```

It may not be 100% safe, so let me know if it could be improved.